# Is it possible to specify a soft delete filter for Hibernate without using HBMXML files?

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion, cfml, hibernate-filters

I'm trying to get "soft deletes" working, as per [this blog entry](http://bears-eat-beets.blogspot.co.uk/2009/10/hibernate-data-filters.html), (which involves enabling `OrmSettings.SaveMapping` to output the HBMXML file for each entity, then manually adding a filter to that file).

If I follow those instructions it works, but this is basically duplicating all the model CFCs into HBMXML files, which both pollutes the file system and creates a maintenance overhead.

**Is there a way to create a filter (or modify the HBMXML file) from within CFML - i.e. *without* generating the HBMXML file?**

(Note: Using the `where` attribute on a cfproperty works for *one-to-many* relationships, but not for *many-to-many* relationships - for those it tries to filter on the join table instead of the other entity.)

Answer (score 1):

Could you consider avoiding soft deletes and using Hibernates Envers instead to maintain a record of the deleted entities in a separate table? This then avoids the hassle of ensuring every query and collection remembers to take into account the deleted condition.

http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/

If you were only interested in auditing deletions then only register the required listeners and ensure you have set org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete to true. If you are keeping only for audit purposes this is a good solution.

Also I do not think that the solution referred to will cascade deletes. Hibernate however allows you to modify the SQL for any operation: overriding the SQL delete operation (with annotations this is done with, for example @SQLDelete(set deleted = 1 ....) on the entity. Deletes will then cascade.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch13.html#querysql-cud

Comment: Thanks, will look into Envers - I think a separate table is acceptable, but will need to check if it's something that can work with CF.

Answer (score 0):

I typically use a 'base' service object to handle all my CRUD for ORM objects and for each ORM object, I extend that base. For items that need 'soft deletes' I simply override the `delete()` method of the service to set a property (typically named 'deleted' to true) then save the entity.

Comment: We've got that - using ColdBox and have all service objects extending a customised version of the VirtualEntityService which works when dealing directly, but not when doing `SomeObjectService.get(1).getRelations()` or HQL - filtering does work for these, but of course seems to need the HBMXML file.